# .NET: Quick way of using a List(Of String) as the Values for a new Key/Value collection?

Tags: vb.net, collections

I have a `List(Of String)` object and need to create a new collection based on the strings' values. The new collection will be of a custom class with two string fields - call them `Key` and `Value` (but it's not the built-in KeyValue class, it's a custom class).

All the values of `Key` will be the same, it's just `Value` that I want to source from the string list. Example:

```
Dim slValues = New List(Of String)({"Cod", "Halibut", "Herring"})
Dim myList   = New List(Of myClass)( ... amazing initialisation line here? )

Class myClass
  Public Key As String   ' This will always be "Fish"
  Public Value As String ' This will be the fish name.
End Class
```

(Note I don't actually have access to the class I'm using, so can't just change it to `Public Key As String = "Fish"` as a default. `Key` must be set at runtime.)

I can of course just do a loop and do it manually, but I'm wondering if there's a whiz-bang way to achieve this as part of the initialisation line?

Comment: All they Keys will be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
Dim myList = slValues.ConvertAll(Of myClass)( _
    Function(s) New YourClass With {.Key = "Fish", .Value = s})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but just had to add `(Of myClass)` after ConvertAll.

Comment: Actually, `(Of myClass)` is not needed. The property should be Value instead of Name though. And a different class name than MyClass should be used because it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: Yep that was just example stuff. The real "myclass" is actually the `SubscriberCustomField` class from the Campaign Monitor API. For some reason the compiler didn't want to accept the ConvertAll code without `(Of SubscriberCustomField)` added in.

Comment: @ingredient_15939, I think, if `myList` were typed then the compiler could detect the correct choice, otherwise it can't choose between the types implemented by the concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to Jodrell's answer using Linq's `Select` function:

```
Dim myList = slValues.Select(Function(fish) New CustomClass With {.Key = "Fish", .Value=fish}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from x in Enumerable.Range(1, slValues.count-1).ToArray 
select new KeyValuePair(of string,myClass) with {.Key=slValues(x),.Value=myList(x)}
```

hope it helps.